# Wangle: /usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to boost::re_detail_106000

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

While installing Wangle, I encountered the following problem. I have already installed Boost, and I don't know why.

```
[ 65%] Built target wangle
Linking CXX executable bin/AcceptorTest
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfolly.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.61.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfolly.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.61.0
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::get_mem_block()'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::put_mem_block(void*)'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106000::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [bin/AcceptorTest] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/AcceptorTest.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[image]

Comment: Are you linking it with `boost_regex-mt` ?

Comment: Sounds like you're linking with 1.61, but `libfolly` was compiled against 1.54 (or the other way around).

Comment: So, did you end up resolving this eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Using clang instead of gcc, removing the atomic check in the CMakeList.txt and disabling tests made wangle build for me on Arch.

It currently won't build with GCC 7 [(Issue)](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/607) and GCC 5 threw a similar issue to yours for me.

`CC=clang CXX=clang cmake . -DBUILD_TEST=0`

(code above does not include the atomic check you need to remove in the CMakeList.txt yourself! Just search for atomic.)